# Specifying starting value in sorting/Sort starting from middle - Progress openedge

Tags: sorting, progress-4gl, openedge

Scenario: I have a char field(name:priority) in my table where values are stored as 1,2,3 and blank("").

```
for each mytable no-lock by priority:
```

This query sorts in this order: blank,1,2,3.

```
for each mytable no-lock by priority desc:
```

And,this query sorts records like this: 3,2,1 and blank.

But i need to sort the records like this: 1,2,3 and then blank. In ascending order but skipping the blank and starting from 1.
Is there any way to sort this out in Progress?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a character field, it's treating the numbers as strings. The ASCII values for the strings "1", "2" and "3" are 49, 50 and 51. Progress treats a blank ("") as ASCII -1. That's why the blank comes first.

Your best bet would be to use two `FOR EACH` statements. First do the non-blank records:

```
FOR EACH mytable NO-LOCK WHERE mytable.priority <> "" BY priority:
```

Then do the blank records:

```
FOR EACH mytable NO-LOCK WHERE mytable.priority = "":
```

If you have your business logic in procedures/functions, you can run those from within the `FOR EACH` loops to prevent any code duplication.

Comment: This pretty much does it. Make sure priority is indexed for maximum performance.

Comment: @bupereira Actually I don't think the index will matter. At least not for the first FOR EACH: the <> will trigger a table-scan/whole-index search.

Comment: @TheDrooper Thats a good suggestion. Actually, in my case, the query used is not that short and simple and i need all the result at once indeed

Comment: @Mahesh In that case, you might try adding a sort field as described in the other answers. If you can't change the schema, copy the records to a temp table and assign the sort field as you do. Then you can use a single FOR EACH on the temp table.

Answer (score 1):

If (only if) theres not that many records in the table perhaps you can copy the records to a temp-table with a new priority and sort the temp-table instead?

If you have million of records this might not be it! Then I would consider simply adding  a new field.

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE MyTable NO-UNDO
    FIELD priority AS CHARACTER
    FIELD txt      AS CHARACTER.

CREATE MyTable.
ASSIGN MyTable.priority = "1"
       MyTable.txt      = "First?".

CREATE MyTable.
ASSIGN MyTable.priority = ""
       MyTable.txt      = "Last?".

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttMyTable NO-UNDO LIKE MyTable
    FIELD newPriority AS INTEGER
    INDEX sortOrder newPriority.

FOR EACH MyTable NO-LOCK:
    CREATE ttMyTable.
    BUFFER-COPY MyTable TO ttMyTable 
        ASSIGN 
            ttMyTable.newPriority = IF MyTable.priority = "" THEN 99999 ELSE INTEGER(MyTable.priority).
END.

FOR EACH ttMyTable NO-LOCK BY ttMyTable.newPriority:
    DISPLAY ttMyTable.
END.
```

Comment: Actually, i am using dynamic query because the query needs to be prepared based on search parameters provided, i dont think its possible, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are scanning /all/ records anyway, you could sort in the BY:

```
define temp-table tt no-undo
   field priority as character
   .

create tt. tt.priority = "".
create tt. tt.priority = "1".   
create tt. tt.priority = "2".   
create tt. tt.priority = "3".   
create tt. tt.priority = "".

for each tt by ( if tt.priority = "" then "4" else tt.priority ):

   display string( rowid( tt ) ) tt.priority.

end.
```